# How can I get the property of an entity at the association memberEnd in UML?

Tags: uml, associations, xtend

Assume I have two entities e1 and e2, and an association 'it' between e1 and e2. Both entities have property p1 and p2. In case I know the association, but i want to ask for e1.p1 and e2.p1, i just simply not know the gramar in xtend how to get it. I tried following

```
def void validateRelationship (Association it) {
    if memberEnds.filter[e|e.p1===true].size==2 {     // here is something wrong        
        // if both e1.p1 and e2.p1 are true, then display an error msg
        ...... 
    }
}
```

But i got compile error like "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Property to Class". How can i solve this problem? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you do not use *it*, where *memberEnds* comes from ? may be `it.memberEnds...` ?

Comment: I found the solution is to use endTypes instead of memberEnds.